# Repeat values in a matrix (R)

Tags: r, sapply, cbind, rep

Here is the code I am working with:

```
A <- matrix(1:9, nrow = 3)
A
cbind(A,A,A)
```

This gives an output:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9]
[1,]    1    4    7    1    4    7    1    4    7
[2,]    2    5    8    2    5    8    2    5    8
[3,]    3    6    9    3    6    9    3    6    9
```

The desired output is...

```
  [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9]
[1,]    1    1    1    4    4    4    7    7    7
[2,]    2    2    2    5    5    5    8    8    8
[3,]    3    3    3    6    6    6    9    9    9
```

In addition I tried this...

```
test <- (sapply(A , function(maybe) rep(maybe,each=3)))
test
```

Which gives an output of:

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9]
[1,]    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9
[2,]    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9
[3,]    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9
```

The help is much appreciated.

Comment: are you trying to get this format on the first attempt or do you have `A` and need to interleave the columns x number of times?

Comment: i don't need to get the format on the first go, I mean of course it would be nice. But yes I am trying to get it on the first attempt.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `rep` with column indexing: `A[,rep(1:3, each=3)]`